# " connect to host gitlab.com port 22: connection refused”

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I've made my ssh key, and wanted to connect to gitlab for the first time. But this message appeared and seems like my computer has blocked access to remote sites...
I don't know how to fix it, and I don't even know why exactly this error occurred!

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/me-u/blahblah_final.git/'
```

I even checked my ssh key, but it was refused access.

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: The log says it's http basic authentiation. When you run `git clone https://gitlab.com/me-u/blahblah_final.git`, it expects you to enter your username and password. If you use ssh url like `git clone git@gitlab.com/me-u/blahblah_final.git`, it expects you to have added your ssh public key to Gitlab.

Comment: Please add the commands that lead to those errors.